# 3 year old SSD under normal use suddenly reports 3% health in its SMART values (97% "Percentage used")

Tags: laptop, ssd, smart

I think this is my first time posting on SuperUser and I'm not super experienced with the subject so please bear with me if I leave out some details on first attempt.

So. We have a 3 year old HP laptop that came with a 512 GB Sk hynix SSD – it never had any problems, but now, out of the blue, it reports 3% health (97% "Percentage used") in its SMART values. I'm not an expert on the subject, but I think its age and usage doesn't really warrant that: my main work laptop has a Samsung SSD that is way-way older (close to 5 years I think?) and is under much larger stress on a daily basis (web development), and yet it reports only 10% "Percentage used" (which I think is fine considering its age and use). So I don't really understand how (and why) the Sk hynix SSD jumped to 97% suddenly.

Truth to be told, I don't really know how sudden that jump to 97% was – the health of that laptop wasn't monitored as closely (it being basically a web surfing machine with occasional photo editing) – we just got a notification from Windows yesterday that things are bad because the SSD has 3% condition. I immediately created a backup (on top of the normal schedule) and installed Hard Disk Sentinel, along with Sk hynix's own disk utility, to check:

[image: HD Sentinel overview]

[image: HD Sentinel details]

[image: Sk hynix overview]

[image: Sk hynix details]

I'm not sure what I expected, but I kind of hoped that the other SMART values will shed some light on what's going on. But, to my eye at least, not really – apart from Percentage used and Critical warning, everything seems to be fine. And although the Sk hynix program does shed some light on what the critical warning exactly is ("Reliability"), it is still quite low on details.

So, the question:

- How worried should I be? Assuming that I store everything important in the cloud and create frequent backups, can I get a few more months out of this drive safely, or should I order a new one right away? (Considering that this is not a small expense.)
- The reason I'm asking that is because I'm kind of suspicious about this drive being manufactured by a brand I have never heard about. Can this be simply a case of planned obsolence (i.e. the laptop's care package expired this summer, so maybe the firmware just decided that it is too old to be used anymore regardless of its actual wear & tear), or is it a genuine problem? If the latter, is there any other SMART value, or other diagnostic thingie, or maybe some logs, that I can check?
- If it is genuinely broken, does it mean that this is a brand to avoid, or me being unlucky and having a faulty unit, or have I done something "wrong" to it? (E.g. this laptop was almost never shut down, just sent to sleep, can that be bad for SSD lifetime?)

Thanks!

Comment: The value for 0xB3 might be the reverse of what you think it is. As in 0 representing that 0% of those blocks have been used. In which case you're currently using 100 of those blocks.

Comment: Nope, spares are good, available.

Comment: SK Hynix isn’t very present in the end-user SSD business, that’s for sure. They’re still one of the world’s largest semiconductor makers. Their OEM hardware is built into many notebooks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Percentage Used: Contains a vendor specific estimate of the percentage of NVM subsystem life used based on the actual usage and the manufacturer’s prediction of NVM life. A value of 100 indicates that the estimated endurance of the NVM in the NVM subsystem has been consumed, but may not indicate an NVM subsystem failure.

Source: https://media.kingston.com/support/pdf/ssd-smart-attribute.pdf. I know this is a Kingston document but the description is part of NVMe specs.

https://nvmexpress.org/wp-content/uploads/NVM_Express_1_2_1_Gold_20160603.pdf

So keyword is *prediction* based on erase/write cycles I assume. This is a finite number and dependent on type of NAND for example but AFAIK it's not written in stone. Other SMART values suggest the drive did not yet run into issues where NAND could not be read from and written to.

Also it's not easy to compare to other SSD's and their usage, it's also related to quality of the NAND chips, type of usage and something like 'write amplification'. Seems HD Sentinel is taking it more seriously than the Hynix software?

The critical warning value 4 or 0000 0100, so 3rd bit (02) set:

> Bit Definition 00: If set to ‘1’, then the available spare space has
> fallen below the threshold. 01: If set to ‘1’, then a temperature is
> above an over temperature threshold or below an under temperature
> threshold. **02: If set to ‘1’, then the NVM subsystem reliability has
> been degraded due to significant media related errors or any internal
> error that degrades NVM subsystem reliability.** 03: If set to ‘1’, then
> the media has been placed in read only mode. 04: If set to ‘1’, then
> the volatile memory backup device has failed. This field is only valid
> if the controller has a volatile memory backup solution.

I am assuming it is triggered by being close to estimated endurance. IOW the drive itself thinks it reached end of life.

So how worried should one be? Hard to tell, but I think the current warning is based on a prediction, not actual things going south. These expected life values are AFAIK based on tests on limited batches and extrapolation.

Answer (score 1):

The "data units written" field show that about 16TB have been written on this drive during his life. This is much lower than the nominal endurance of any SSD, even entry-level ones. It looks difficult to find the specs of this drive but as a rule of thumb the endurance of a consumer-grade SSD is around 500 to 1000 times its capacity: for your drive it means between 250 and 500 TB of data. You are far from that, 16 TB written is between 3% and 6%... So I suspect that the "percentage used" field contains just the opposite, i.e. the "percentage remaining".

Answer (score 1):

Not to sound pessimistic or anything, but as soon as you plug in an SSD and write to it, it will start dying. Having a drive at 3% health is more of an indicator that you might want to start thinking about lining up a replacement,

You’ve used less than half of the write cycles the drive is capable of enduring, so it’s not like the drive is on its last legs or anything, but you’re to the point where you want to keep an eye on it. Once it gets down to less than 50% (it goes from green to yellow), it’s probably time to start seriously thinking about a replacement. This is not because it’s likely to poop out on you next week, but because you’ll want to allow for backup before swapping it out.

I am not factoring time into this, however. If that drive has been in use for five years and you’re at 3%, it’s likely that you’ll be OK for another few years, but it’s something that you’ll want to check periodically. If the drive has been in use for a year or so, then it’s a bit more urgent. Start creating Backup as soon as possible.